# d3.js ¿Cómo abrir la url en una nueva pestaña?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Necesito abrir estas urls en una nueva pestaña. Ahora mismo se abren en la misma.

```
var data = [
{title: "1", url: "gallery1.html"},
{title: "2", url: "gallery2.html"},
{title: "3", url: "gallery3.html"},
];



    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.example.url; })
    .attr("xlink:title", function(d) { return d.example.title; });

svg.selectAll('.add-url-node')
   .on('click',function(d){
      location.href = 'target.url.com';

   });
```

He probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido con window.open, pero con mis conocimientos limitadísimos no he sido capaz.

He intentado esto sin éxito:

```
<script>    
window.open(url);      
</script>
```

y

```
window.open(link, "_blank")
```

y

```
data.forEach(function(elem){
window.open(elem.url,"_blank");
});
```

y

```
.attr("xlink:target", "_blank")
```

Aquí os dejo el código entero por si alguien quisiera echarle un ojo: http://jsfiddle.net/kajihood/pa8sdtrt

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si quieres que se abra en una nueva pestaña ponle el valor `_blank` al atributo `target` (que no `xlink:target`). Aparte de eso, el código que pones no tiene mucho sentido y el JSFiddle tiene varios fallos que hacen que no corra

Answer (score 2):

```
.attr("target","_blank", function(d) { return d.example.url; })
```

Esto era lo que necesitaba.
Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Sería útil que lo marcaras como respuesta que te ayudo a solucionar tu pregunta.